# Linux: Find and Execute Concurrent xterm

Tags: linux, concurrency, find, execute, xterm

I am trying to run a client and server for each instance in a collection of folders. I tried this command:

`$ find ./ -name "Makefile" -execdir xterm -title "Server" -e "timeout -s sigint 8s ./server > serverLog.txt" \; -execdir xterm -title "Client" -e "timeout -s sigint 5s ./client > client1Log.txt" \;`

But this ran the server in an xterm window for 8 seconds and then closed that window and ran the client in an xterm window for 5 seconds. I need the client and server to run at the same time for each Makefile found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run two commands concurrently you have to use the ambersand `&`, which will send first execution to background and continues with the next one. So you have to exec something like

`cmd1 & cmd2 &` or `cmd1 & cmd2` , it depends on what you want.

Next you have to escape ambersand while inside `-execdir`, which accepts one command. One way to do this is

`find [params] -execdir sh -c 'cmd1 & cmd2' \;`

example:

`find [params] -execdir sh -c 'xterm -e "sleep 8" & xterm -e "sleep 5"' \;`